# Linux how to get a console where you can select, copy, paste move your cursor like in a normal text editor?

Tags: linux, console

How to setup a console in linux where the text behaves like in a normal text editor, I want to be able to select, copy, paste, move with ctrl+arrow, move with mouse like in a normal text editor. How to do that ?

Comment: by copy and paste you mean with mouse or with ctrl+c/ctrl+v?

Comment: @jiggunjer ctrl+c/ctrl+v but i would also like other features such as put my cursor where i want with the mouse etc